# Lie subalgebra as the intersection of the subalgebra and the Lie subalgebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, free-lie-algebras

Let $X = (X_1, \dots X_q)$ be indeterminates. Let $A(X)$ be the free algebra over $X$. Let $L(X) \subset A(X)$ be the free Lie algebra over $X$.

I consider some finite set $Y \subset L(X)$ and denote similarly $A(Y)$ the subalgebra of $A(X)$ generated by $Y$ and $L(Y)$ the Lie subalgebra generated by $Y$. (Assume that $Y$ is chosen such that $A(Y)$ is free over $Y$ as an algebra and that $L(Y)$ is free over $Y$ as a Lie algebra).

Of course, one has immediately $L(Y) \subset A(Y)$ and $L(Y) \subset L(X)$, because $Y \subset L(X)$. So $L(Y) \subset A(Y) \cap L(X)$.

> It is true that the converse inclusion holds, i.e. $A(Y) \cap L(X) \subset L(Y)$, and if so, is there a simple proof of this fact?

Comment: Your notation is a bit misleading, since in most cases $A(Y)$ is not free over $Y$ as algebra and $L(Y)$ is not free over $Y$ as Lie algebra.

Comment: Indeed, the examples for $Y$ I had in mind satisfy this condition. I added this precision to the question. Thank you.